# Best index configuration for sql statement in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing

I have the following compound sql statement for a lookup and I am trying to understand that are the optimal indexes (indices?) to create, and which ones I should leave out because they aren't needed or if it is counter productive to have multiple.

```
SELECT items.id, items.standard_part_number, 
items.standard_price, items.quantity, 
part_numbers.value, items.metadata, 
items.image_file_name, items.updated_at
FROM items LEFT OUTER JOIN part_numbers ON items.id=part_numbers.item_id 
AND part_numbers.account_id='#{account_id}'
WHERE items.standard_part_number LIKE '#{part_number}%' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT items.id, items.standard_part_number, 
items.standard_price, items.quantity, 
part_numbers.value, items.metadata, 
items.image_file_name, items.updated_at
FROM items LEFT OUTER JOIN part_numbers ON items.id=part_numbers.item_id 
AND part_numbers.account_id='#{account_id}'
WHERE part_numbers.value LIKE '#{part_number}%' 
ORDER BY items.standard_part_number
LIMIT '#{limit}' OFFSET '#{offset}'
```

I have the following indices, some of them may not be necessary or could I be missing an index?... Or worse can having too many be working against the optimal performance configuration?

```
for items:
CREATE INDEX index_items_standard_part_number ON items (standard_part_number);

for part_numbers:
CREATE INDEX index_part_numbers_item_id ON part_numbers (item_id);
CREATE INDEX index_part_numbers_item_id_and_account_id on part_numbers (item_id,account_id);
CREATE INDEX index_part_numbers_item_id_and_account_id_and_value ON part_numbers (item_id,account_id,value);
CREATE INDEX index_part_numbers_item_id_and_value on part_numbers (item_id,value);
CREATE INDEX index_part_numbers_value on part_numbers (value);
```

Update:
The schema for the tables listed above

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name TEXT,code TEXT UNIQUE,created_at INTEGER,updated_at INTEGER,company_id INTEGER,standard BOOLEAN,price_list_id INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE items (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,standard_part_number TEXT UNIQUE,standard_price INTEGER,part_number TEXT,price INTEGER,quantity INTEGER,unit_of_measure TEXT,metadata TEXT,image_file_name TEXT,created_at INTEGER,updated_at INTEGER,company_id INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE part_numbers (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,value TEXT,item_id INTEGER,account_id INTEGER,created_at INTEGER,updated_at INTEGER,company_id INTEGER,standard BOOLEAN);
```

Comment: Show the database schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outer joins constrain the join order, so you should not use them unless necessary.
In the second subquery, the `WHERE part_numbers.value LIKE ...` clause would filter out any unmatched records anyway, so you should drop that `LEFT OUTER`.

SQLite can use at most one index per table per (sub)query.
So to be able to use the same index for both searching and sorting, both operations must use the same [collation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation).
LIKE uses a case-insensitive collation, so the ORDER BY should be declared to use the same (`ORDER BY items.standard_part_number COLLATE NOCASE`).
This is not possible if the part numbers must be sorted case sensitively.
This is not needed if SQLite does not *actually* use the same index for both (check with [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html)).

In the first subquery, there is no index that could be used for the `items.standard_part_number LIKE '#{part_number}%'` search.
You would need an index like this (NOCASE is needed for LIKE):

```
CREATE INDEX iii ON items(standard_part_number COLLATE NOCASE);
```

In the second subquery, SQLite is likely to use `part_numbers` as the outer table in the join because it has two filtered columns.
An index for these two searches must look like this (with NOCASE *only* for the second column):

```
CREATE INDEX ppp ON part_numbers(account_id, value COLLATE NOCASE);
```

With all these changes, the query and its [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output look like this:

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT items.id, items.standard_part_number,
items.standard_price, items.quantity, 
part_numbers.value, items.metadata, 
items.image_file_name, items.updated_at
FROM items LEFT OUTER JOIN part_numbers ON items.id=part_numbers.item_id 
AND part_numbers.account_id='#{account_id}'
WHERE items.standard_part_number LIKE '#{part_number}%' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT items.id, items.standard_part_number, 
items.standard_price, items.quantity, 
part_numbers.value, items.metadata, 
items.image_file_name, items.updated_at
FROM items JOIN part_numbers ON items.id=part_numbers.item_id 
AND part_numbers.account_id='#{account_id}'
WHERE part_numbers.value LIKE '#{part_number}%' 
ORDER BY items.standard_part_number COLLATE NOCASE
LIMIT -1 OFFSET 0;
1|0|0|SEARCH TABLE items USING INDEX iii (standard_part_number>? AND standard_part_number<?)
1|1|1|SEARCH TABLE part_numbers USING COVERING INDEX index_part_numbers_item_id_and_account_id_and_value (item_id=? AND account_id=?)
2|0|1|SEARCH TABLE part_numbers USING INDEX ppp (account_id=? AND value>? AND value<?)
2|1|0|SEARCH TABLE items USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
2|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
0|0|0|COMPOUND SUBQUERIES 1 AND 2 (UNION ALL)
```

The second subquery cannot use an index for sorting because `part_numbers` is not the outer table in the join, but the speedup from looking up both `account_id` and `value` through an index is likely to be greater than the slowdown from doing an explicit sorting step.

For this query alone, you could drop all indexes not mentioned here.

If the part numbers *can* be searched case sensitively, you should remove all the COLLATE NOCASE stuff and replace the LIKE searches with a case-sensitive search (`partnum BETWEEN 'abc' AND 'abcz'`).

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed and informative answer. I am just now returning to this to part of our project again and realized I had not selected your answer. We don't need any case sensitive searches so I'll leave in the COLLATE NOCASE entries.

Comment: How much of your answer above maps over or does not map over to MySQL? We will be using both MySQL and SQLite in this solution because we build the SQLite db files for shipping to the mobile app but we want to maintain the server side db in MySQL now since we will have multiple servers and multiple client connections to a SQLite db doesn't seem like a good idea. We will maintain the MySQL as master and then build a copy as SQLite file for the mobile app to download but all of the same indexing and select statement optimization questions apply for both.

Comment: see the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)